# Why is Xamarin.iOS "being referenced" on my Xamarin.Android project?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I created a Xamarin.Android project and I can't build it. I get this error:

> Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
>   Could not load assembly 'Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'. Perhaps it doesn't
>   exist in the Mono for Android profile? File name: 'Xamarin.iOS.dll'
>   at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
>   reference, ReaderParameters parameters)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1
>   assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(ICollection`1
>   assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() Claims.Mobile.Droid

I don't understand, why would a Xamarin.Android project try to reference that dll? I created the project from scratch and the only thing I did so far was to reference my PCL and create one activity.

### Update

[image]
[image]

Thanks

Comment: You are creating a Xamarin native or forms project?

Comment: @Rohit "native", it's a Xamarin.Android project, not XF.

Comment: Does your code use any namespace that might have come from Xamarin.iOS.dll within the android project perhaps by mistake? Or in a PCL that is referenced by the droid project.

Comment: This doesn't sound right off first glance. Do you have reproduction steps or a sample project that we can dig into further? What libraries did your PCL include?

Comment: I just added 2 pictures with the DLLs referenced by my PCLs. @JonDouglas All I did was to create a Xamarin.Android project and reference those two libs. The project builds without those references, but I can't find any reference to Xamarin.iOS on them. Clint, I doubt :/